# writing to pdf with d_ply, multiple ggplots, looping over multiple variables

Tags: r, loops, pdf, ggplot2, plyr

Does it take an additional loop to write a series of plots from ggplot to a single .pdf rather than as a separate .pdf for each plot? Otherwise this code does what I want: subset by type, write series of ggplot arrays to pdf--one grid plot for each location overlayed by color-coded years, y axis label is type, x axis label is day.  Other suggestions/improvements?

```
d_ply(m,"type",function(a) {
  p <- ggplot( a, aes(y=result, x=day, color=colorcode)) + geom_point()
  q <-p + plotOptions + ylab(a$type) 
  print(q)
  ggsave(paste(a$type,".pdf"), plot=q)               
  })
```

sample dataframe

```
 a<-factor(c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)))
 b<-factor(c(rep("2006",4),rep("2007",4)))
 d<-c(rep(13,4),rep(14,4))
 e<-factor(c(rep("birds",4),rep("fish",4)))
 f<-sample((25:100),8)
 g<-factor(c(rep("2003-12",4),rep("2003",4))) 
 m<-data.frame(a,b,d,e,f,g)
 colnames(m)<-c("location","year","day","type","result","colorcode")

 names(m)<-tolower(names(m))


 backColor <- "moccasin"
 plotOptions <- list(scale_colour_manual(values = c("skyblue","royalblue" ), name="year"), 
                facet_wrap(~ location, ncol=4))
```

Thanks for any comments.

Update

So, my initial draft of the code tried what you suggested, but the result was an empty pdf:

```
pdf(file="test.pdf")
d_ply(m,"type",function(a) {
  p <- ggplot( a, aes(y=result, x=day, color=colorcode)) + geom_point()
  p + plotOptions + ylab(a$type) 

  }) 
dev.off()
```

That was just due to not explicitly printing the update to p?  The online discussion about this goes in all sorts of directions, some very complicated, some with calls to ggsave, etc.  That's why I wound up with the call to ggsave.

One last question:  to combine values in two factor fields for ylab, say to tack on a unit, would something like this work: a[c("f1", "f2"), sep = "")]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple plots per PDF file, then this is one way to do it:

```
pdf("allinone.pdf")
d_ply(m,"type",function(a) {
  p <- ggplot( a, aes(y=result, x=day, color=colorcode)) + geom_point()
  print(p + plotOptions + ylab(a$type))
}) 
dev.off()
```

Comment: When the expected result of a function call in R is printing some sort of object, and the result is instead an empty file, is this a good indicator that the explicit print call is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple plots in a single pdf:

```
library(grid)
vplayout <- function(x, y)
  viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
pdf("AllInOne.pdf", width = 12, height = 12)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
print(p, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(q, vp = vplayout(1, 2))
print(p, vp = vplayout(2, 1))
print(q, vp = vplayout(2, 2))
dev.off()
```

Comment: That's actually kind of neat--specifically directing plots to locations on a grid.  Sometimes ggplot is just what's needed, sometimes its just useful to have more direct control over formatting.